# listview adapter not updating after removing an item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

Hello am trying to delete an item from my listview am able to delete item from my db but my adapter is not getting updated I have attached the code below`

```
public class SavedPolygonFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements RefreshListener {
private static String LOG_TAG = SavedPolygonFragment.class.getName();

private String message = "No message";
private ListView          shapeList;
private TextView          textView;
private Button            startMainBtn;
private SavedShapeAdapter savedShapeAdapter;
private long              shapeId;
private float             scaleFactor;
private List<Shape> savedShapes = new ArrayList<>();
private StartDrawingListener startListener;
private DeleteShapesDialog   deleteDialog;

public SavedPolygonFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    startListener = (StartDrawingListener) activity;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    savedShapes = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("shapes");
    AssetLog.verbose(LOG_TAG, "savedshapes.size " + savedShapes.size());
    shapeList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.shapeList);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.polygonTitle);
    startMainBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.gotoMain);

    startMainBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startListener.startMainReceived();
        }
    });

    if (!savedShapes.isEmpty() && !savedShapes.equals(null) && savedShapes.size() != 0) {
        textView.setText("Polygons");
        shapeList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        startMainBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        if (savedShapeAdapter != null) {
            savedShapeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {

            savedShapeAdapter = new SavedShapeAdapter(savedShapes, getActivity());
            shapeList.setAdapter(savedShapeAdapter);

            shapeList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    MainActivity_.intent(getActivity())
                            .savedProjectId(ProjectShapesActivity.projId)
                            .scaleFactor(ProjectShapesActivity.scaleFactor)
                            .shapeId(((Shape) view.getTag()).getShapeId())
                            .lineId(-1)
                            .pointId(-1)
                            .start();
                }
            });


        }
    }
    else{
        shapeList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        startMainBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        textView.setText("Sorry no shapes are saved");
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    registerForContextMenu(shapeList);
}

@Override
public void onRefreshPressed() {
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    shapeId = info.id;
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.deleteShapes, Menu.NONE, "Delete");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.editShapes, Menu.NONE, "Edit");

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.refresh:
            return false;

        case R.id.deleteShapes:
            if(deleteDialog == null){
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("SHAPE", "SHAPE");
                bundle.putLong("shapeId", shapeId);
                deleteDialog = new DeleteShapesDialog();
                deleteDialog.setArguments(bundle);
                deleteDialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "showDeleteDialog");
            }
            return true;
        case  R.id.editShapes:
            return true;

    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}


 public void onDataChanged(long shapeid) {

    Shape shape;
    for (int i = 0; i <savedShapes.size() ; i++) {
        shape = savedShapes.get(i);
        if(shape.getShapeId() == shapeid){
            savedShapes.remove(i);
            shapeList.removeViewAt(i);
            shapeList.invalidate();
            savedShapeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

Now when user selects yes from ***deleteDialog*** i wrote a callback to my activity and in the corresponding methods this is what I do

```
SavedPolygonFragment polygonFragment = new SavedPolygonFragment();
 polygonFragment.onDataChanged(shapeId);
```

Can somebody show me whats wrong

/////EDIT 1

```
 public void onDataChanged(long shapeid) {

     savedShapeAdapter.removeItemById(shapeid);

}
```

and my adapter

```
public void removeItemById(long itemId){
    for(int i =0; i< shapeList.size() ; i++){
        if(shapeList.get(i).getShapeId() == itemId){
            shapeList.remove(i);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am able to delete item from my db but my adapter is not getting
>   updated

Problem is caused by :

```
savedShapes.remove(i);
```

line.

Currently removing item from ArrayList which is in `SavedPolygonFragment` class, not from ArrayList which is used by Adapter to fill ListView.

Using current approach try this way will work by setting new Adapter every time:

```
       if(shape.getShapeId() == shapeid){
            savedShapes.remove(i);
            savedShapeAdapter = new SavedShapeAdapter(savedShapes, getActivity());
            shapeList.setAdapter(savedShapeAdapter);
            savedShapeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        }
```

But this is not optimize solution to create and set new object of Adapter every-time when want to update ListView.

Right approach is create a method in `SavedShapeAdapter` class for removing item for ArrayList which is used by Adapter and then call it inside `onDataChanged` method:

```
public void deleteRowItem(int index){
  this.savedShapes.remove(index);
  this..notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now call `deleteRowItem` when want to delete row item from ListView :

```
if(shape.getShapeId() == shapeid){
    savedShapeAdapter.deleteRowItem(i);
    break;
 }
```

Comment: I tried like u said but give me NullPointerException at savedShapeAdapter.removeItemById(shapeid);.

Comment: I used a breakpoint on that line it says savedShapeAdapter = null

Comment: @elsa: means not  initializing  savedShapeAdapter object before onDataChanged method called. so your update code

Comment: @elsa: Change `onDataChanged ` method as `public void onDataChanged(long shapeid) { if(savedShapeAdapter !=null){savedShapeAdapter.removeItemById(shapeid);}}`